# Display progress of process that runs on backend

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, xaml, mvvm, wcf-ria-services

I'm developing Silverlight 4 LOB application and need to provide correct visualization of process that runs on back-end. Basically I need to show progress of operation that is currently running on server side.

Is there any correct way of implementing this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RIA doesn't support the server notifying the client. So the only way would be to find a way to query the progress periodically or just display a spinny wheel. Of course, splitting up the process as much as possible would help too (so you could display step 3/5 Fooing the bar [Spinny Wheel]).

Comment: Using RiA for such purposes is not the main goal. I think and hope that there should be correct ways of displaying this info.

Comment: Well... you can always use sockets :S, but that's a little sucky.